# Matrix of linear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

I would like to see if the following is true:

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field. Let $M$ be a $(a+n-1)\times a$ matrix of linear forms in $R$. If $I_a(M)$ is $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$-primary, then $I_a(M)=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)^a$.

Thank you.

Comment: I seem to be getting this from the exactness of the Eagon-Northcott complex, still very surprising to me.

Comment: Could you show this for $a=1$? If yes, then please post your proof.

Comment: It might be good to explain what the notation $I_a(M)$ precisely means. Is it the ideal generated by the entries of $M$? Why is there an $a$ in the index, if it already depends on $M$?